Fitting outer edge of a rough rectangle with rounded corners

I have detected edges of an image with openCV (shown with green points) as
        edges = cv2.Canny(gray, canny_0, canny_1)
        kernel = np.ones((int(kernel_size), int(kernel_size)), np.uint8)
        edges = cv2.dilate(edges, kernel, iterations=1)


Now I need to find out the quadrilateral that tightly fits this contour (all the points should lie within the quadrilateral) - shown with red lines on the diagram. I am open to using open CV or scikit or any other suitable python library.

Hello, in order to help you, users would need access to the unaltered raw data. Please post the raw image along with the code that eventually led to the creation of the results in your question.

source data required. [mre] -- even with that, opencv doesn't have good functions for this. you're lucky that it's a rectangle, so a minAreaRect might work well enough, but only without any debris enlarging the contour. -- you are trying to locate some type of playing card, eh? please do a little research on how others have done that. this has been asked lots of times.

Does this answer your question? OpenCV - How to find rectangle contour of a rectangle with round corner?

@toyotaSupra Unfortunately, my problem is more complex. Firstly the contour is not regular rounded rectangle but contains a few deviating points. Secondly it's not perfectly vertical but at an angle as you can see in the image. It may need something like NP least squares or sklearn PCA, but I am unable to get satisfactory results with that so far.

And the fitting outer polygon may not even be a rectangle, it could just be a quad with corner angles other than 90

Have you tried cv2.minAreaRect? Just in case, here is the example https://theailearner.com/tag/cv2-minarearect/

@VardanGrigoryants Thanks for the link, but looks like minAreaRect returns a rectangle (corner angles 90) whereas I am looking for quad where all sides could be of different length. approxPolyDP gives the quad corners but the rectangle is not outer but inner.

you ought to present source data. so far, nobody could have guessed that you need quads rather than rectangles. your question's title says "rectangles". [ask], [mre]

Based on the comments, you can try the following:
# use cv2.THRESH_BINARY if the detected edges is brighter than background
thresh, binary_image = cv2.threshold(edges, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# finds outer boundary due to cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL parameter
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# takes the first contour, in your case it should be the only one
cnt = contours[0]

# approximates contour to polygon, you may need to play with epsilon
epsilon = 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
quad_approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, epsilon, True)

quad_img = np.zeros_like(binary_image)

# -1 means all contours will be drawn, 2 is thickness
cv2.drawContours(quad_img, [quad_approx], -1, (255, 255, 255), 2)

Note: I haven't tried it, since you haven't provided the original image, i.e. edges, but hope this will work for you.
For outer boundaries you can also use skimage find_boundaries function with mode="outer", like this: find_boundaries(quad_img, mode="outer")
